# Enable scrolling inside a Fragment that uses TabLayout and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

**Hello!
I want this view to be scrollable:**

[image]

As you can see, the "TEMP CONTENT" in TAB1 is just there to simulate temporary content that may come up.

What I want to do now is to make the whole page scrollable. What I managed to do is to make the content of TAB1, so, the content of the TabLayout, scrollable, but that's not that what I want to do. As described, the whole page should be.

**That is the Layout that is holding the view:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="at.codecrane.whosnext.MainActivity">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:srcCompat="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_face"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Temp Name"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>



        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="General" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Statistics" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**And this is the fragment-layout for the ViewPager- Content:**

```
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEMP CONTET"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEMP CONTET"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEMP CONTET"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEMP CONTET"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEMP CONTET"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use scroll view instead of linear layout as root in your first xml

Comment: I tried to use scroll view instead, but then no content at all is displayed in the viewpager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Scrollview` and `NestedScrollview` Together.

here is an example [Code](http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/07/nested-scroll-views-in-android.html)

1. use `NestedScrollview` in your View pager fragment.
2. For your activity layout add `Scrollview` as root tag and add `android:fillViewport="true"`

Comment: A part of your answer is correct. When I use the Scrollview as root tag and add the android:fillViewPort="true" it works, kind of. But, I have to set the height of the view pager to 2000 dp, to let the scroll view do his job.
I think that the issue now is to set the height of the view pager. 
But, I don't know the height of the ViewPager, i just replace the view pager with the content of the fragment. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I don't want the ViewPager to be nested. I just want the whole page to scroll, as it would be a normal page.

Comment: Do you have any idea for dynamic height?